# Dropbox Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, dropbox, connect

I am trying to Connect to Dropbox Using the below method.
When I am running the program it is giving both request code and response code 200 whether the USER_NAME and PASSWORD is correct or wrong ,why?

```
import com.dropbox.core.*;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Locale;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class Main {




    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {
        // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
        final String APP_KEY = "";
        final String APP_SECRET = "";
        final String USER_NAME= "";
        final String PASSWORD= ";
        DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig(
            "JavaTutorial/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
        DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);
     // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
        String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
        System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
        System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
        System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");

        URL obj = new URL(authorizeUrl);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + authorizeUrl);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
         URL url = new URL(authorizeUrl);
         HttpURLConnection req = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
         BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
          String userpassword = USER_NAME + ":" + PASSWORD;
          String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode( userpassword.getBytes() );
          req.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+
                encodedAuthorization);
          int reqCode = req.getResponseCode();
          System.out.println("request code"+reqCode);
//      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
//              new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
//      String inputLine;
//      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
// 
//      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
//          response.append(inputLine);
//      }
//      in.close();
// 
//      //print result
//      System.out.println(response.toString());
       // Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(authorizeUrl));
//      Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
//          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
//              return new PasswordAuthentication ("USER_NAME", "PASSWORD".toCharArray());
//          }
//      });


        String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();
     // This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
        DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);

        DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, authFinish.accessToken);

        System.out.println("Linked account: " + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not open the authorizeUrl by code. Instead, open in a browser and do authorize this app to use your account.

It is returning status 200 (OK) every time because the login page was found, requiring you to do a login or, if already logged in, authorize your app.

If you are planning to enable users to do this on your website, the tutorial demonstrates:

> With the authorization URL in hand, we can now ask the user to authorize your app. To avoid the hassle of setting up a web server in this tutorial, we're just printing the URL and asking the user to press the Enter key to confirm that they've authorized your app.
>
> However, in real-world apps, you'll want to automatically send the user to the authorization URL and pass in a callback URL so that the user is seamlessly redirected back to your app after pressing a button.
>
> Source: [Using the Core API in Java](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java)

To continue your tutorial, simply copy & paste URL on your browser, do authorize and then you'll get the authorization code to continue the process.

Comment: I don't want to open a url in a browser.  this is the requirement

Comment: So I think that this is not the way to work. This API requires the app to be authorized via web.

Comment: I have a system that does a backup, of course it should not require a browser to be open, so I used the example to generate my access token (using a browser) and put in a constant, and afterwards I only had to use it. It would be a problem if I needed different accounts each time, but it worked perfectly for my needs.

Comment: is it possible to do it via programmatically ??

Comment: Do you mean get the authorization or do a upload without user interaction?

Comment: i want to authenticate

Comment: If you really need to bypass, you can try to simulate a navigation using [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) for example. Remember: you have to get an auth code only once to be able to do unlimited uploads afterwards.

Comment: one thing tell me i want something like that i don't want to open any third party browser. i only want to do this work using command line. is it possible? or else if we need to open the browser then browser page must be open automatically and it should automatically authenticate the apps programmatically

Comment: With Apache HttpComponents you could navigate without using a browser, did you take a look?

Comment: But why Dropbox is having this restriction(should I say feature) that requires auth code generated via browser?

Comment: Because user has to authorize your usage. If you're planning to use your own account, you can make a manual authorization, and then use the token for good.